# How to do an ALTER TABLE with a table in-use

Tags: mysql

I have a script that runs 24-7 on a table to perform necessary functions on it. However, when it is running, it is almost impossible to do an `ALTER TABLE ADD INDEX` statement, as it seems like it just hangs indefinitely. Is there any way around this? How should I go about adding this index?

Comment: So what is so critical that you cant stop it for a few minutes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Alter table statement is getting a metadata lockout. You cannot perform your alter statement while another transaction is in process on the same table.  Since your script runs 24-7, it is not possible to do what you are asking.

To ensure transaction serializability, the server must not permit one session to perform a data definition language (DDL) statement on a table that is used in an uncompleted explicitly or implicitly started transaction in another session. The server achieves this by acquiring metadata locks on tables used within a transaction and deferring release of those locks until the transaction ends. A metadata lock on a table prevents changes to the table's structure. This locking approach has the implication that a table that is being used by a transaction within one session cannot be used in DDL statements by other sessions until the transaction ends.

You can read more about this [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/metadata-locking.html) at dev.mysql.

Answer (score 1):

Version 5.6 has `ALTER TABLE ... ALGORITHM=INLACE ...` to do `ADD INDEX` and several other ALTERs without blocking everything.

pt-online-table-alter (from Percona.com) can do it in older versions of MySQL.  It uses a TRIGGER.

Comment: If you are using InnoDB, there should almost never be a "table lock".  The row locks that normal transactions have, plus the row locks that the Trigger will acquire, will interact with each other.  However the delays will usually be unnoticeable.